# Export subsite and Import in another web app (means another db)

Tags: 2013, web-application, export, import, sub-site

I have one web application with site collections. Then I have a subsite inside. I want to export this subsite (and only this one), and import it in a new web app I will create.

Question is : Is this possible ? I'm guessing, ofc, with powershell Import/Export-SPWeb. This seems easy. But When I will import it, will my subsite, becoming a entire site, will use a the new web app's database ? Because I want to separate its database.

If you have any advice :)

Thanks

Nico.

**UPDATE1**: The `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` exit with errors : `HRESULT : 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)` on some files (like AllItems.aspx). But it creates documents libraries as I expected. But it does not create the home page, and the personnalization I did.

And the documents libraries it created returns a 404 not found when I try to open them...

I tried using -UseSqlSnapshot with my `Export-SPWeb` but it seems like my SQL version does not support this. But I don't think that this parameter would have change anything.

Comment: If I save my subsite as a template, and then create the new one with this template, maybe it will work. Just an idea, I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact apples to apples comparison, but here it is......

I used the following link to backup and restore.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erica/archive/2013/11/26/customer-question-renaming-site-collections-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

I used the powershell script under paragraph "Move Site Collection from Test to Prod".

Backup-SPSite http://sp-test.contoso.net/sites/research –Path  E:\BackupServer\BackupShare\ResearchBackup.bak -UseSqlSnapshot

**Restore-SPSite http://sp.contoso.net/sites/research –Path E:\BackupServer\BackupShare\ResearchBackup.bak**

There is another paragraph (Renaming) that had it all in one script (I believe), but I elected to do it in two separate scripts.

Backup-SPSite http://sp.contoso.net/sites/HR –Path E:\Backup\HRBackup.bak -UseSqlSnapshot Restore-SPSite http://sp.contoso.net/sites/HumanResources -Path E:\Backup\HRBackup.bak Remove-SPSite http://sp.contoso.net/sites/HR –GradualDelete

I ran bolded Restore command in a separate script.  It created a new Site Collection and put it into an open ContentDB.

Started the PS script with:  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.

Comment: Please add more details, your answer is to dependent on the link (if it breaks it will be of no help to future readers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb`. But the `Export-SPWeb` log show me lots of error while exporting pages (`HRESULT : 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)`). And the `Import-SPWeb` tells me that it will work, only if the tree structure is exactly the same. Maybe the `Backup-SPSite` works properly. I will tset out things, and come back when it will be done. The `Backup-SPSite` works while the site is in use ? And this command created its own collection site ? Really ?

Comment: The `Backup-SPSite` saves the whole collection site no ? If I just want to save one subsite, will it works ? **EDIT : test it, and it does not work since I'm trying to save/move a subsite, not a site collection.**

Comment: Try using stsadm -o export -url http:\\your.site -filename e:\export.cab -includesecurity

I was able to export a subsite in a Site Collection. I user stsadm -o import -url http:\\your.site -filename e:\export.cab -includesecurity to put it in another.

It is time consuming.  It would go through the export process before getting error feedback, but you could find out what they are.

Answer (score 1):

> Question is : Is this possible ?

Yes. You can export-import subsites. Ensure that You have all same features activated in new site-collection (target site-collection)

> But When I will import it, **will my subsite, becoming a entire site**,
>   will use a the new web app's database ?

You cannot export-import site collections ('sites', as You say). But You can create another site-col and restore (import) subsite there.

> Because I want to separate its database.

You can create site-collection in same WSS_Content database, or add separate database for this new site-collection (SharePoint puts new site-collections using its own order, but You can set first database to readonly and SharePoint will use new database. Use [this article](https://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-sitecollection-specific-content-database.html) and google)